# Calculation within Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, variables, replace

I had a crazy idea.

I want to do a calculation within a regular expression but I'm not sure if it's possible. Basically I have a line that says:

```
Category:
```

And every time you click a button it will say:

```
Category:
Category 1:
Category 2:
```

etc. I am doing a string of functions on a jQuery selector right now as such:

```
var newHTML = selector.closest('.row').clone().html().replace(/(Category)(\s)(\d)/g,'$1$2' + (parseInt('$3') + 1)).replace('Category:','Category 2:');
```

So it does the first replace and if it's the original 'Category' it won't match and will run the second replace. If it does match, I want it to increment the number on the end of the expression by one. I thought maybe I could parseInt() the variable and add one but that doesn't work since `parseInt('$3')` appears to return NaN and doesn't recognize the variable as an integer.

I know there are plenty of other ways to do this but I just stumbled across it, stumped myself and always like to find any answer to a good question...

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What are you expecting `parseInt('$3')` to return? Because of the `$` it cannot parse that into a number. Have the regex compute what `$3` is then modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in many other languages, JavaScript evaluates the arguments **before** they are passed to the function. So in your case `'$1$2' + (parseInt('$3') + 1))` is evaluated *first*, which results in the string `'$1$2NaN'`, and *that* is passed to `.replace`. `parseInt('$3')` is `NaN` because the string `'$3'` cannot be converted to a number:

```
> parseInt('$3')
NaN
```

If you want to perform any computation with the matches, you have to pass a function as second argument:

```
.replace(/(Category)(\s)(\d)/g, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
  return $1 + $2 + (parseInt($3) + 1));
})
```

(of course you can name the arguments whatever you want)

You can learn more about passing callbacks to `.replace` in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Comment: Very clean and easy to understand. Thank you, I've never used a callback within replace!

Answer (score 1):

Further to @FelixKling's answer here is a working demo, just to show what adjustment you might have make.

```js
$('.cat').on('click', function() {
    $(this).html(function(i,html) {
        return html.replace(/(Category)(\s?)(\d*)/g, function(match, x, y, z) {
            y = y || ' ';
            z = z || 0;
  return x + y + (+z + 1);
});
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat">Category</div>
<div class="cat">Goint with Category  Blah Blah Blah</div>
```